# Volume preserving transformation between a cube and a ball (solid sphere)?

Tags: continuity, volume, transformation, spheres, closed-map

I have searched a lot online but I am unable to find such transformations, I only find difficult to read research papers and also [this](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html) which is a nice mapping from cube to sphere but not with the restriction of volume.

My context may help. I have a set of RGB points, meaning points that lie on $[0-255, 0-255, 0-255]$ 3D space. This set of points forms a Cube in space. I want to map each $(r, g, b)$ to a new $(r', g', b')$ in a continuous manner. So, what I have thought, is to map the cube into a sphere, rotate the sphere around an axis, and then map back from sphere to cube. The reason I need this mapping, is because if I rotate directly on the cube, the new rgb point may fall out of the cube range. The sphere gives me the advantage of staying inside the boundaries.

The reason I need the volume preserving restriction, is that I want the "density" of each initial color to remain the same after the transformation.

Any help ?

Comment: I understand that you want to map the cube to the sphere, and then map back to the cube again, all in a continuous way. There is however, no continuous bijection between the cube and the sphere. Could you map from the cube to the ball, then rotate, and map back to the ball?

Comment: @Meneer-Beer What do you mean there is no continuous bijection between the cube and the sphere ? What I want is 3d cube -> 3d sphere -> rotate the sphere -> 3d cube. By continuous I mean starting from an $(r, g, b)$ point on cube and then performing a small rotation, I want the new point to be near the initial point.

Comment: Any continuous bijection from a compact space (such as the cube)
onto a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism, but the cube and the sphere are not homeomorphic, since the sphere has an interior hole, but the cube does not. I suggest you approach like this: cube-->3d ball-->rotate 3d ball-->cube.

Comment: @Meneer-Beer Yes, my bad, english is not my native language so I am lost in terminology. By sphere, I mean a solid sphere, so yes, a ball.

Comment: Ah, then I would first translate your cube to be centered around the origin (by subtracting 255/2 from each coordinate). Then your map from the centered cube to the ball could be $(r,g,b)\mapsto \frac{max\{|r|,|g|.|b|\}}{\sqrt{r^2+g^2+b^2}}(r,g,b)$. It does not preserve volume, but after mapping back to the cube from the ball with the inverse of this map it DOES preserve volume. For a volume preserving map from the square to the disk you can try to generalize the result of Shirley and Chiu from 1997, but I don't immediately see how this generalization works.